# How to add a div on comment fields / edited

Tags: comments, forms

How to put Comment forms like Author,Email,Url inside a div..

I am using args but that doesn't work for me

```
<?php
    if ( post_password_required() ) {
        return;
    }
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php // You can start editing here ?>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                printf( // WPCS: XSS OK.
                    esc_html( _nx( 'One comment on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s comments on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'nuvola' ) ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ),
                    '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>'
                );
            ?>
        </h2>

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-above" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'nuvola' ); ?></h2>
            <div class="nav-links">

                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'nuvola' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'nuvola' ) ); ?></div>

            </div><!-- .nav-links -->
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-above -->
        <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation. ?>

        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=nuvola_comments'); ?>
        </ol>

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'nuvola' ); ?></h2>
            <div class="nav-links">

                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'nuvola' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'nuvola' ) ); ?></div>

            </div><!-- .nav-links -->
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
        <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation. ?>

    <?php endif; // Check for have_comments(). ?>

    <?php
        // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
        if ( ! comments_open() && '0' != get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.', 'nuvola' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $args = array(
-----------------------------------------------
      'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

  'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

  'url' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'domainreference' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
    '" size="30" /></p>',
-----------------------------------------------
        );?>
    <?php comment_form( $args ); ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

I tried to put  at `'Author' => '<div>..code..'` 
and close the div at `'url' => '..code.. </div>'` but it's not working. Every change i make, not work on preview.. I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Please provide more details, or try posting your comment template.

Comment: ye sorry about that, now i posted full comment.php and the way i am trying to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `comment_form()` isn't quite correct with your arguments being loaded in.

You need to pass in `'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),` into a new argument. Attached is an example of what you would need to update.

### Fields you want to have filled out

```
$fields =  array(
  'author' =>
    '<div class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
  'email' =>
    '<div class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',

  'url' =>
    '<div class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'domainreference' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
    '" size="30" /></div>',
);
```

### Comment Form Arguments

```
$comments_args = array(
    // change the title of send button 
    'label_submit'=>'Send',
    // change the title of the reply section
    'title_reply'=>'Write a Reply or Comment',
    // remove "Text or HTML to be displayed after the set of comment fields"
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    // redefine your own textarea (the comment body)
    'comment_field' => '<div class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></div>',
    'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
);

comment_form($comments_args);
```

The only item of note is the `'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields` in the last line of the `$comment_args`. This will allow you to pass in update form fields.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.