# Why default comment fields don't show up?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I am developing my first theme and I would like to customize the default comments fields (name, email, url).

I understand how to do that, this is not my question. My problem is that those fields don't show up at all. I only have the textarea and the submit button. I tried to install others themes to see if this problem come from my own code, but the fields don't show up either. That's the reason why I am not posting any code. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please show (in code) how you did that? In an [edit] to the question and not with a comment, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a div on comment fields / edited](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237546/how-to-add-a-div-on-comment-fields-edited)

Answer (score 0):

Without code and based upon what you are doing, my advise would be to set WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php. If there are any errors causing the fields not to display, they are likely to show up. Especially since you are coding a custom theme, there is a good chance of errors somewhere you wouldn't expect. If you encounter errors, post them here so we have a little bit more info about what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. There was no error. It was actually very simple (and a little silly). You need to log out if you want to see the fields ...